# How to force tomcat reload to reset static AtomicBoolean

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In my web app, I have a Spring `@Configuration` class with a `@Bean` annotated method which creates a client for a service my app depends on. The client is created via a builder which enforces the existence of only one client instance by internally using a `private static AtomicBoolean isClientCreated` variable.

When one of my web app class change forces tomcat reload (configured via `PreResources` in `web.xml`), the client creation fails because even after the bean gets destroyed, the private static AtomicBoolean `isClientCreated` remains `true`.

How do I reset this static value on tomcat reload?

Comment: Don't use `static AtomicBoolean`  but instead create the field for singleton bean

Comment: Unfortunately, the builder is a 3p library that we have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PostConstruct` or `@PreDestroy` to annotate your config (or any suitable singleton bean). Then reset the flag in any of the methods.

See [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, the AtomicBoolean is a private static in a third-party library that I cannot change. So, this doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: You can still access the field via reflection. Just get the field and call setAccessible(true) then you can call and reset the field